# htaccess rewrite rule to index.php?p=pagename

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this htaccess code to create a rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1.php [L,QSA]
```

i want to rewrite pages like

`http://my.domain.net/index.php?p=tickets/openticket` to look like `http://my.domain.net/tickets/openticket`

but its just showing index.php without the `?p=`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code as your **first rules**:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess? Are there more rules there? What URL did you use to test this?

Comment: i have just moved it to the root of my.domain.net subdomain and it shows page not found. i also tried it in the root and it just shows the index.php file

Comment: Test this code and it worked on my localhost in `DocumentRoot/.htacces`. Post your latest .htaccess in question and give me full URL that you are using to test this.

Comment: so i have a subdomain (my.domain.net) and .htaccess in the main root, my full ht access code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/8SEQxhKB and when i go to my.domain.net/tickets/openticket it just shows index.php whereas it should be showing index.php?p=tickets/openticket

Comment: Do you want it to show: `index.php?p=tickets/openticket` (very strange since others want to show `/tickets/openticket` and load content in background from `/index.php?p=tickets/openticket`)?

Comment: sorry, i may have got it the wrong way round, i want the url to show /tickets/openticket but load index.php?p=tickets/openticket

Comment: that is what above rules do but you need to move these 2 rules **before other rules** you already have.

Comment: ok i have just put the rules in your answer right at the top just below RewriteEngine On but still the same. its just loading index.php rather than index.php?p=tickets/openticket

Comment: the htaccess file will work fine if its in the main root of the domain, it doesn't need to be in the root of the sub domain?

Comment: See updated code. I am not able to get good sense of your setup. I have experienced many site owner unaware of where exactly is the `DocumentRoot` of their domain.

Comment: htaccess file located in public_html, subdomain (my.domain-uk.net) located in public_html/customer. 

i want the URL http://my.domain-uk.net/tickets/openticket to load http://my.domain-uk.net/index.php?p=tickets/openticket

Comment: Can you paste `VirtualHost` section of your subdomain in your question?

Comment: That is where your sub domain is setup in your Apache config.

Comment: I'm using a web host on a shared server so i don't have access to this

Comment: do i need the htaccess file in the root of domain-uk.net or in the root of my.domain-uk.net ?

Comment: I'm using your code in your answer, i have changed ^my\.domain\.com$ to be ^my\.domain\-uk\.net$ ...is that correct?

Comment: Check updated code, this goes in root of `my.domain-uk.net`. Also create a `info.php` in the root of subdomain with this code: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and open that in your browser as `http://my.domain-uk.net/info.php`. Tell me what you see it there as `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

Comment: document root looks like /home/username/public_html/my

Comment: Ok did you try updated code? Is .htaccess even enabled? Copy/paste your .htaccess code from `/home/username/public_html/my/.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]

try this.